# Does anyone already parallelized mosaic function for rasters in R?

Tags: raster, r, parallel-processing

Does anyone already paralleled mosaic function for rasters in R?

It seems that `snow` still doesn´t deal with this on an automatic way.

The idea is something like this:

```
r1<-stack("fit__test23KLR.img")
r2<-stack("fit__test23KKR.img")
r3<-stack("fit__test23KKS.img")
r4<-stack("fit__test23KLS.img")

ff <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4) mosaic(x1, x2, x3, x4, fun="mean") 

beginCluster(35) 
cl <-getCluster() 
m1 <- clusterR(r1, r2, r3, r4, fun = ff, export="mosaic") 
endCluster()
```

Each stack r1, r2.... are:

```
dimensions  : 2516, 412, 1036592, 93  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
range between: -2.5 to 2.5
```

Comment: How many rasters are you mosaicing, and what are you doing in overlap regions? Because you might be able to write `mosaic(r1,r2,r3,r4)` as `mosaic(mosaic(r1,r2),mosaic(r3,r4))` and you could do the inner mosaics in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a reasonable solution using the `gdalUtils` package:

```
library(gdalUtils)

gdalbuildvrt("fit__test23KLR.img", "r1.vrt", sd=1)
gdalbuildvrt("fit__test23KKR.img", "r2.vrt", sd=1)
gdalbuildvrt("fit__test23KKS.img", "r3.vrt", sd=1)
gdalbuildvrt("fit__test23KLS.img", "r4.vrt", sd=1)

gdalbuildvrt(c("r1.vrt", "r2.vrt", "r3.vrt", "r4.vrt"), "m1.vrt", sd=4)

gdalwarp("m1.vrt", "finalmosaic.tif",
         t_srs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs", multi=TRUE)
```